# Differences between Quite, Fairly, Rather, and Pretty

Tags: grammar, adverbs

I read in a grammar book that *Fairly* is less strong than the others in meaning, and also the meanings of the rest are the same, I mean each of them is as strong as the others. But, I read in a dictionary that in American English, *Quite* is much stronger than the others and the rest are the same. I'm a bit confused. I need a comparison between them.

Comment: In general, in British English I would say they were all about equal, similar to _moderately_ or _somewhat_. However, to describe something as _rather good_ or _pretty good_ is more enthusiastic than _quite good_ or _fairly good_! To further complicate matters, _quite_ can also mean _completely_, as in "Have you quite finished?"

Comment: I think this question presupposes it's *possible* to arrange *Quite, Fairly, Rather,* and *Pretty* (also *very, a bit, enough, tolerably, sort of,* etc.) in some generally-accepted sequence of "intensity". Which it aint, so the question is POB.

Comment: @FFRM, I agree, it's not one dimensional. But what does POB mean?